# Discover emulators without adb

Tags: android, adb

Adb can discover all running emulators with

```
adb devices
```

how does he detect the running emulators? Is it possible to list the running emulators without adb?

Comment: ["It locates emulator/device instances by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by emulators/devices."](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: means the emulator opens a tcp-port?

Comment: AFAIK, that's how it works.

Comment: With `emulator -list-avds` you can list existing Emulators, but not whether they are running or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADB is probably just doing a port scan / attempting to open the TCP ports that JimmyB mentioned.

NMAP can do the same. This should reveal the ports...

```sh
$ sudo nmap -sS -p 5555-5585 localhost -oG - 
# Nmap 7.80 scan initiated Thu Aug  6 18:26:30 2020 as: nmap -sS -p 5555-6000 -oG - localhost
Host: 127.0.0.1 (localhost) Status: Up
Host: 127.0.0.1 (localhost) Ports: 5555/open/tcp//freeciv///    Ignored State: closed (445)
# Nmap done at Thu Aug  6 18:26:31 2020 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.15 seconds
$
```